# Java code (URLConnection - remote get method) in HTML (Blogger.com post)

Tags: java, html, httpurlconnection, blogger, urlconnection

In Blogger post I have this snippet

```
<applet codebase="https://droidsnip.googlecode.com/hg/" height="300" archive="text.jar" width="300" code="Google.class">
```

and have this java code stored at google code:
public class Google extends java.applet.Applet {
        public static void main() {

```
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        String result = sendGetRequest(
                "http://www.google.com", null);

        g.drawString(result, 30, 30);
    }

    public static String sendGetRequest(String url,
            String requestParameters) {
        String result = null;
        if (url.startsWith("http://")) {
            try {
                URL url1 = new URL(url);
                URLConnection conn = url1.openConnection();
                // Get the response
                BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        conn.getInputStream()));
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                String line;
                while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                }
                rd.close();
                result = sb.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

And i do not get any result in post, but I get a normal html response using Eclipse.
What can be a problem with Blogger?
Btw, if I just use

```
g.drawString("test", 30, 30);
```

I get a string on the post, so it works

Comment: If you have a new question, please post a new question. Do not edit a different question.

Comment: but it i kind of related to the previous problem.. ok, will try to explain it in a new q

Comment: It's related, but no the same, otherwise you would not have a new question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unsigned Java applets are [restricted in what they can](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html) do to prevent malicious use. If your applet isn't signed, then it can only connect to the server on which it is hosted (i.e. droidssnip.google.com in this case).

Here's a reference on how to [sign an applet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/plugin/developer_guide/rsa_signing.html). Note that if you use a self-signed certificate (one you generate yourself with keytool), then you'll be prompted with a security warning when the applet runs. To avoid this, you'll need a certificate from a trusted Certificate Authority.

Comment: Now i got a little another problem.. Described it in the post

Answer (score 0):

I guess you hit a security restriction so called "same origin policy": an applet can only talk to the server it was downloaded from. See details here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html

Update: Besides signed applets the other workaround might be to implement a "proxy" servlet. In this case the sevlet polls google (ie. implements the sendGetRequest method) and talks to your applet (ie. the applet reads your servlet which in turn reads google).

Comment: that is true, but now i got another problem, i describe it in the post